# Unit Test - Cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I am learning Unit tests with React (new to both), I am stumped at why this isn't working

I want to Test my App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import PokemonDetail from "./Components/PokemonDetail";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/:offset?" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/pokemon-detail/:id" element={<PokemonDetail />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my Unit test

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "../../App";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

describe("App", () => {
  it("should render Home component by default", () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/"]}>
        <App />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    const homeElement = screen.getByTestId("home");
    expect(homeElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("renders the PokemonDetail component when the URL is /pokemon-detail/:id", () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/:offset?"]}>
        <App />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    const pokemonDetailElement = screen.getByTestId("pokemon-detail-id");
    expect(pokemonDetailElement).toBeInTheDocument();
    screen.debug();
  });
});
```

The error I am getting is

> `Error: Uncaught [Error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app.]`

But I am only using it in the `App` and no where else. I get initiating the `MemoryRouter` is basically wrapping a router around the router inside the App's router, but how can I test offset etc without?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `react-router@6` it is an invariant violation to render any router inside another router.

Promote the `BrowserRouter` out of the `App` component so `App` renders *just* the routes and can be wrapped by ***any other*** router during unit testing.

index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

App.jsx

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import PokemonDetail from "./Components/PokemonDetail";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/:offset?" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/pokemon-detail/:id" element={<PokemonDetail />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The unit test files can now correctly wrap the `App` component with any router more suitable for unit testing, e.g. the `MemoryRouter`.

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "../../App";

describe("App", () => {
  it("should render Home component by default", () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/"]}>
        <App />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    const homeElement = screen.getByTestId("home");
    expect(homeElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("renders the PokemonDetail component when the URL is /pokemon-detail/:id", () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/:offset?"]}>
        <App />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    const pokemonDetailElement = screen.getByTestId("pokemon-detail-id");
    expect(pokemonDetailElement).toBeInTheDocument();
    screen.debug();
  });
});
```